# Magento 2 /var/page_cache gets HUGE

Tags: full-page-cache, magento-2.1.9

I am running a **Magento 2.1.9** Shop with the built in FPC enabled. After a couple of days the **/var/page_cache** folder has over 10GB more in size, after some more days its 15GB and so on, it never stops, I had to clear that folder when it was at 220GB! The store has ~18000 products.

I know I can delete that folder daily, but this results in the website being slow again. Is there some option I am missing?

Comment: I have the same issue on Magento 2.3.0. have researched several article but could not find solution

Comment: Do you find any solution?